# How to do 3 table JOIN in UPDATE query with two ' x ON'

Tags: mysql, join

Can you join 3 tables with detailed information using two x ON?
If not, I'm open to how to get results in a different way.
What is the best way of getting this result?

Example: I receive the error below when trying to run this code.

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a 
JOIN (SELECT b.col1, b.col2, b.col3
FROM TABLE_B b
GROUP BY b.col1
ORDER BY b.col2 ) x ON a.join_col = b.join_col
JOIN (SELECT c.col1, c.col2, c.col3
FROM TABLE_C c
GROUP BY c.col1
ORDER BY c.col2 ) x ON a.join_col = c.join_col
SET a.column = c.column + b.column
WHERE a.column = 'xyz'
```

*Error I get:*
**Error updating record: Not unique table/alias: 'x'**

I understand the basic functionality of joining 2 tables and 3 tables

Joining 2 tables:

```
   UPDATE TABLEA a 
   JOIN TABLEB b ON a.join_col = b.join_col  
   SET a.column = b.column
```

Joining 3 tables

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a 
    JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.join_col = b.join_col
    JOIN TABLE_C c ON a.join_col = c.join_col
SET a.column = c.column + b.column
```

Note: If I do the basic above joining 2 or 3 tables, this works without problem. The problem happens when I try to add extras in my code and it doesn't like it.

Comment: Why did you give the same alias `x` to two different tables in the join?

Comment: OMG its that simple!
I didn't understand that you need two different variables. i'll close this out! Thanks

Comment: Well ... due to limitations of stack overflow I can't close it out, so I added an answer. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do was add a different variable than just 'x' as the alias just like below where I added 'z'.

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a 
  JOIN (SELECT b.col1, 
               b.col2, 
               b.col3
        FROM TABLE_B b
        GROUP BY b.col1
        ORDER BY b.col2 ) x 
    ON a.join_col = b.join_col
  JOIN (SELECT c.col1, 
               c.col2, 
               c.col3
        FROM TABLE_C c
        GROUP BY c.col1
        ORDER BY c.col2 ) z 
    ON a.join_col = c.join_col
SET a.column = c.column + b.column
WHERE a.column = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

inf I understand right seems you need

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a 
INNER JOIN TABLE_B b on a.join_col = b.join_col 
INNER JOIN TABLE_C c ON a.join_col = c.join_col
SET a.column = c.column + b.column
WHERE a.column = 'xyz'
```